# CheckBox checked, clicked ok button but the value of checkbox not reflected on next page

Tags: watin

I have a checkbox and a ok button on a webpage,

**steps to be performed using Watin Automation:**

1. click checkbox
2. click ok button

**expected result :** A row gets added to concerned checkbox on next page

**Actual Result with Manual execution :** A row gets added on next page.

**Actual Result with Watin Automation :** No row is added on next page. Even after checkbox is checked.

I have used following code to check the checkbox

```
 browser.Frame(Find.ByTitle("Frametitle")).CheckBox(Find.ById("CheckboxId")).Click();
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    if (!browser.Frame(Find.ByTitle("Frametitle")).CheckBox(Find.ById("CheckboxId")).Checked)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("Checkbox is not checked, checking it once again");
                    }
```

Also I have used javascript to check the checkbox and clicked the button, but still it is not working 
Javascript code is as follow:

```
 browser.RunScript("document.getElementById('CheckboxId').click();", "javascript");
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks,

Saurabh

Answer (score 0):

Try to focus on the element and send ENTER key and check.